# What Control in ASP.net to show the notice loaded from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a new to ASP.net.  Sorry if this problem is so simple with some people.

In my webpage, main frame includes two smaller frames: leftcol, centercol. In centercol I want to show the news (sort by day, time) loaded from SQL DB. I want the news showing like that:

[image: the frame of news]

I really dont know which Control in ASP.net is suitable??? Datalist, Listview???

Comment: What about this view is important to you? Nothing is going to be an exact match for that view. You'll have to style and build all the html to support this on your own.

Comment: I know, but I think it should have a Control support loading the news in Database. That picture is just a example for the way that news is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.you can try using repeater.

[repeater sample](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/repeater-control-example-in-aspnet.html)

2.Gridview..

[Gridview Sample](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html)

U can use these two controls to fetch and display data..MOreover you can do paging and sorting based on criteria by defining properties..Apart from this you need to make few styles inorder to have your own look..

Comment: If you found this as useful mark as answer and give upvotes.. so that it may help in future for others..

Comment: I voted it at the moment I saw, But I can't do it within 6 minutes, I so I forgot :D

Comment: Oh dear, more problem, can you help me to find an idea. I want the first line (first new) is showed biger than other (like the picture above). Can you help me?